# How to read this time output?

Tags: time, last-command

Why is there a `1+` in `Wed Dec  9 19:34 - 20:50 (1+01:15)`?

I find two such entries when I look at the output of `last reboot`:

```
...
reboot   system boot  4.2.5-1-ARCH     Fri Dec 11 10:31 - 10:32  (00:01)
reboot   system boot  4.2.5-1-ARCH     Thu Dec 10 20:50 - 23:50  (02:59)
reboot   system boot  4.2.5-1-ARCH     Wed Dec  9 19:34 - 20:50 (1+01:15)
reboot   system boot  4.2.5-1-ARCH     Wed Dec  9 19:27 - 19:34  (00:06)
reboot   system boot  4.2.5-1-ARCH     Wed Dec  9 19:22 - 19:27  (00:04)
...
```

and

```
...
reboot   system boot  4.3.3-2-ARCH     Fri Jan 29 15:55 - 16:10  (00:14)
reboot   system boot  4.3.3-2-ARCH     Fri Jan 29 13:37 - 13:44  (00:07)
reboot   system boot  4.3.3-2-ARCH     Thu Jan 28 07:02 - 13:44 (1+06:41)
reboot   system boot  4.3.3-2-ARCH     Thu Jan 28 01:20 - 01:22  (00:01)
reboot   system boot  4.3.3-2-ARCH     Thu Jan 28 04:43 - 04:44  (00:00)
...
```

Comment: 1+ means 'one day plus' that many hours...

Comment: @ridgy in the second example, the second and third lines conflict. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know why `last reboot`shows this behaviour, that two different system boot end at the same time (I have these as well). `last -F reboot` will show more clearly the end date and time.

Comment: @ridgy -F solved all my confusion. Can you please convert your two comments into an answer so that I can accept it?